# Adblock filter allow a specific div?

Tags: adblock

How do you unblock a specific div using Adblock filters?

For e.g. StackOverflow `.network-items` is blocked by AdBlock. How can this specific div be un-blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two ways (see [adblockplus.org](https://adblockplus.org/en/filters#elemhide_exceptions)):

1. Disable element hiding for the whole domain (e.g. `@@||example.com^$elemhide`).
2. Create an exception filter for each filter that is being applied on that element (e.g. `#@#.network-items` would disable the filter `##.network-items`). In Firefox you can see all active filters by choosing "Open blockable items" from the Adblock Plus icon menu.

Generally, if you think that something shouldn't be blocked and a [manual filter list update](https://adblockplus.org/en/faq_basics#update-filterlists) didn't help then the [Adblock Plus forum](https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=2) is the best place to report that.